# Convertir mi URL a una URL amigable error de ruta

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Cuando visito mi sitio web con la URL no amigable todo se me muestra bien sin problemas, pero al visitar mi sitio con la **URL** amigable este funciona pero tal parece que las rutas dentro de la paginas están incorrectas y sucede esto:

[image: Asi se muestra la pagina con la url amigable]

Cuando paso el cursor por encima de cualquier enlace este me muestra una ruta incorrecta por ejemplo `thecanario/article/3/login` cuando en verdad debería de ser `thecanario/login` pero cuando entro con la **url** todo fea que no es amigable todo se me muestra de forma correcta y no logro saber donde esta el problema.

### Archivo .htaccess

```
# Eliminar el .php en todos los archivos
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# URL Amigable
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2

# Error 404
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/thecanario/404
```

### Enlace donde creo mi URL:

`<a href="article/<?=$id_more_post?>/<?=$titleMoreURL?>">`

Si creen que debo mostrar otro tipo de información que tal vez estoy olvidando, solo dejármelo saber

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el módulo `Rewrite` de _Apache_ puede interpretar las URL amigables y redirigir a la ruta correcta, pero es en PHP donde debes generar la URL. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que creas los enlaces.

Comment: He colocado la parte donde construyo la url porque siento que lo demás donde obtengo el id del post y el titulo del articulo ya es algo innecesario, pero si usted siente es importante lo hago

Comment: Primero corrige el enlace: `header("Location: article/$id_post/$titleURL");`, después haz las adecuaciones necesarias en `.htaccess`.

Comment: Pero el `header("Location: article/$id_post/$titleURL");` yo creo que esta correcto y si no esta correcto por favor escríbeme la url correcta. El .htaccess lo tengo de esta manera, dime usted si es correcto `Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2`

Comment: Discúlpame pero es que no soy experto en url amigables, incluso mi conocimiento es nulo en este campo

Comment: La URL amigable está en mi comentario anterior; en tu pregunta la estás generando de otra forma. Solo actualiza eso en tu PHP y ya puedes comenzar a investigar la parte del `.htaccess`, seguramente con alguna de las respuestas que ya te proporcionaron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es algo simple de resorber y hay varias formas. Una que puedes hacer pero que yo no recomiendo es que le coloques la URL completa a tus links y scripts, ya sea copiando la **url** en el navegador y pegándola de forma completa, eso eliminaría tu problema.

Lo siguiente que puedes hacer y que yo te recomiendo es colocar debajo del titulo entre el `<head>` de tu pagina la etiqueta de **html5** `<base>` y allí le especificas solo el dominio de tu **url**

### Ejemplo:

```
<head>
  <base href="https://www.tudominio.com/">
</head>
```

Recuerda que puedes colocarle perfectamente tu dirección de host local como por ejemplo

```
<head>
  <base href="localhost/miweb" target="_blank">
</head>
```

Y tampoco abría problema.

Con hacer eso, ya estaría listo y en tu archivo todo funcionaria de manera perfecta

Answer (score 1):

Yo uso esta metodología, quizás te ayude.

Directorio

```
 pruebaURL
  |_ files
  |    |_ inicio.php
  |    |_ pagina1.php
  |    |_ pagina2.php
  |_ index.php
  |_ .htaccess
```

Primero preparo el index.php

```
<?php
const SERVERURL = "http://localhost/pruebaURL/";

$id = 7; //id o dato que quiero pasar por la URL
?>
<h1>Index</h1>

<ul>
 <li><a href="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>inicio/">Inicio</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>pagina1/<?php echo $id; ?>/">Pagina 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo SERVERURL; ?>pagina2/">Pagina 2</a></li>
</ul>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $views = explode("/", $_GET['page']);
    include 'files/'.$page[0].'.php';
    } else {
        include 'files/inicio.php';
}

?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?view=$1
```

Ejemplo pagina1 para tomas los valores pasados por URL

```
<h1>Pagina 1</h1>
<?php

$codigo = explode("/", $_GET['page']);

if($codigo[1] == 7){
    echo 'Hola usuario ID #'.$codigo[1];
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo como esto para hacer lo que quieres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Nota : 'id' es el nombre de tu variable get ($_GET["id"])
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LO que tu quieres lo he conseguido, metiendo tu .htaccess e index dentro de una carpeta article y en el htaccess el siguiente codigo

```
Options All -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: No ha sucedido nada, mi url sigue igual `http://localhost/thecanario/article?id=1&title=el-dron-ori%C3%B3n-e-entra-en-el-mercado-mundial`

Comment: Pero la url no va cambiar , tu tienes que colocarla  como quieres que se muestre http://localhost/thecanario/article/3/lugares-%E2%80%98top-secret%E2%80%99-de-la-urss-que-se-convirtieron-en-ruinas , y si te permite es porque funciona

Comment: Es que me lanza un error 500

Comment: La URL se escribe como me gustaria, pero lo malo es el error 500 que me lanza

Comment: Yo lo utilizo de esta manera el .htaccess   Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1
Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ article.php?title=$2

Comment: Esta manera tambien la utilizado antes Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1&title=$2

Comment: El error 500 aun persiste, no se que estaré haciendo mal pero necesito ayuda, me interesa que mi url sea amigable

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta y agregué unas imagenes, como te explico ahi podrias crear una carpeta article y dentro poner tu index.php y el htaccess, de esa manera se logra la figura que deseas